# Ajax to PHP, not updating?

Tags: php, ajax

Here is my index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addHit(str){
    $.post("http://www.site.com/addclick.php", { id: str })
};
</script>

<a href="javascript:;" onClick="addHit('928'); return false;">update ID 928 with 1 click</a>
```

Here is my `addclick.php`

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `x` = `x` + '1' WHERE `id` = '" . $id . "'");
```

If I have `WHERE id = '1'` it updates `row 928` perfectly, but when it is set as the post variable, it doesn't. The only thing I can think of is that the ajax call is not parsing the ID properly.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: Is it inside of `var_dump($_POST)` ?

Comment: I suggest don't use http://www.site.com/addclick.php instead /addclick.php I have a same problem before.

Comment: $.post("/addclick.php", { id: str }) or $.post("addclick.php", { id: str })

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure, but it could be because in jquery you didn't put the the id in quotes like this:

```
$.post("http://www.site.com/addclick.php", { 'id': str })
```

It's considering that you id is a var and not the name of the variable...

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

WHy not check what $_POST is before blindly inserting it into your database? I could hack up a script that sets `id = 'Robert\'; drop table students --` and kill your database.

```
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
$sql = "UPDATE `table` SET x=x+1 WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die("query failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: This wasn't a php issue, I didn't post the real PHP code, it was an example. On top of that, this is development, not a working script on a website.